# Chrome untrusted terminal and/or crosh

Tags: google-chrome

I have been trying to find  a cure forever I tried to disable it worked for two of them now I try to tell some people my mom has a masters in tech I might be able to try to do it with her but i cant seem to get it to go away is it nothing to worry about or is it a virus someone help or my cmputer might get hacked

Answer (score 1):

Crosh is a shell for the OS devs to use, it was implemented not as a virus, but for the devs to work on the system on a single chromebook I believe. Don't worry, you won't get hacked either, trust me on this one.
If you get into it again, and don't want to, close it or enter the command "exit", without the quotations.

Answer (score -1):

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c]=k[c]||c}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('1-0:',2,2,'untrusted|chrome'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

http://chrome-untrusted:/terminal/html/terminal.html

Comment: Take a look at the following link to write a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer